# Div scrolling to top after contents are refreshed/reloaded

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, refresh

Got a Div being refreshed every 5 seconds.  The div has scrolling set to scroll so that user can scroll, but when the refresh happens the div scrolling goes back to the top. Any ideas how I can keep the scroll position after the div is refreshed?

Here's my CSS:

```
#alerts_container {
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #666;
}
```

JS:

```
refresh_alerts = setInterval(function (){
    $('#leftside div#alerts_container').load('staffhome.php #alerts_container' );
}, 5000)
```

HTML:

```
 <div id='alerts_container'>
  <?php 
   include_once('includes/my_alerts.php'); 
  ?> 
 </div>
```

Used SKS's answer to get this to work for me, but I did have to change his code up a bit:

```
var isScrolling = false;
var lastScrollPos = 0;
var counter = 0;
$(function() {
    $('#alerts_container').bind("scroll", function (){
       isScrolling = true;
    });
    refresh_alerts = setInterval(refreshContent, 5000);
    function refreshContent() {
        lastScrollPos = $('#alerts_container').scrollTop();
        if (!isScrolling) {
            $('#alerts_wrapper').load('staffhome.php #alerts_container', function () {
             $('#alerts_container').scrollTop(lastScrollPos);
            });
        }
      isScrolling = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am checking the checkmark to answer my questions.  Is there another way to mark something as having an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get scroll height inside your scroll handler using `.scrollTop` and then set it after `.load`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/hRreU/8/) -- Try scrolling all the way down and wait 5 secs for the new contents to get updated.

Below is an abstract from the demo,

```
var lastScrollPos = 0;
$('#scrollingDiv').on('scroll', function() {
    lastScrollPos = this.scrollTop;
});
```

and in `.load` callback

```
$('#leftside div#alerts_container').load('staffhome.php #alerts_container' , function () {
   $(this).scrollTop(lastScrollPos);
});
```

Comment: Marked this answer but I did have to change a few things to get it to work for me. Look at my Edit

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't replace the content and only append the new information to the container that would simply work.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

http://api.jquery.com/append/